# View Controllers with transparent background overlapping when segueing (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uibackgroundcolor

I have multiple view controllers set up with push segues, they are all a grey colour with 50% opacity. The problem is when pushing to next VC they overlap and it doesn't look great at all.

I have been looking online and only answer I could find was to remove the animation. I do not want to do this as I have set up tap gesture swipes and the UI do not look that pleasing if there isn't the push animation!

Please see video example of it in action here -

http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=2ez6x7a%3E&s=9#.Vnh6SJOLSX0

Comment: I am asking myself that you are customizing back button first screen on the video? Can you give me the reason for it?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Nope! No solution unfortunately, I had to go with a solid colour in the end. The only solution I can think of it to set it up as a pageview/walkthrough controller. So the content will move but the VC View dose not.

Comment: I am facing the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56795553/last-controllers-content-visible-while-pushing-a-new-view-controller). Any working solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution I:**

If you are ok to remove the animation, Set animated `false` on `UINavigationController.pushViewController` in Swift

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(viewController, animated: false)
```

**Solution II:**

If you don't, then you may need to hide the current ViewController before you push the new viewcontroller as follows:

```
yourCurrentViewController.view.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: he knows remove animation can solve it. But he don't want it.

Comment: Could you give some code example for Solution ll? Thanks

Comment: check my updated answer. By the way, I still do not get why you make your viewcontroller transparent, and do not want to see previous viewcontroller. If you do not show it, then do not use transparent.