# last controller's content visible while pushing a new view controller

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, uinavigationcontroller

I am facing a very basic problem while pushing a view controller. When I am pushing a new controller, the last controller's content is visible on screen. I am pushing the new controller as follows:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(reviewFeatureViewController, animated: true)
                }
```

[image]

Comment: Did you solved that issue?

Comment: @Peterses Yes, I solved the issue by refractoring `reviewFeatureViewController `. Autolayouts for custom table cells needs to update.

Answer (score 1):

I had that too occasionally. 
What helped for me was making sure the backgroundColor is not .clear
try this:

```
viewController.backgroundColor = .white
```

Comment: The background color of view is white. But the issue still persists.